# My spring boot application is working perfectly when started in STS but if I try with jar, this method kills it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In the Spring Tool Suite the application is working perfectly.

When I run my application in browser I get this response:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Sep 06 20:46:04 CEST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No message available
```

localhost:8080, index page perfectly fine. If I hit the button that calls the "/getinfo" page what makes the "getTrades()" to run, I get this whitelabel error.

I found out that it dies at these lines in the "public List getItemNamesAndIDsFromTXT()" function:

```
String content = "";
        try {
            content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("GetInfoService.java --> getItemNamesAndIDsFromTXT() --> content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath())); --> " + e);
        }
```

This is my (only) controller:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @Autowired
    GetInfoService gis = new GetInfoService();

    @Autowired
    CalculateProfitService cp = new CalculateProfitService();


    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getIndex(Model model) {

        return "index";
    }


    @RequestMapping("/getinfo") 
    public String gotTheData(
            @RequestParam(name="fromCity") String fromCity, 
            @RequestParam(name="toCity") String toCity, 
            @RequestParam("profitMinimum") int profitMinimum, 
            @RequestParam("profitMaximum") int profitMaximum, 
            @RequestParam("auctionTax") int auctionTax, 
            Model model) {  


        model.addAttribute("trades", gis.getTrades(fromCity, toCity, profitMinimum, profitMaximum, auctionTax));    

        return "index";
    }
}
```

This is my service:

```
@Service
public class GetInfoService {

    public List<Item> getItemNamesAndIDsFromTXT() {

        File file = null;
        try {
            file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:ids");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("GetInfoService.java --> getItemNamesAndIDsFromTXT() --> file = ResourceUtils.getFile(\"classpath:ids\"); --> " + e);
        }
        String content = "";
        try {
            content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("GetInfoService.java --> getItemNamesAndIDsFromTXT() --> content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath())); --> " + e);
        }
        List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(content.split("\\n"));

        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String i : lines) {
            String uniqueName = i.substring(i.indexOf(':') + 1, i.lastIndexOf(':')).trim();
            String tier = uniqueName.substring(0, 2);

            String itemName = i.substring(i.lastIndexOf(':') + 2).trim();
            if (uniqueName.contains("@")) {
                itemName = itemName + uniqueName.substring(uniqueName.indexOf('@'));
            }
            items.add(new Item(uniqueName, itemName, tier));

        }

        return items;
    }

    public ArrayList<Offer> getOffers(String fromCity, String toCity, int auctionTax) {
        final List<Item> items = getItemNamesAndIDsFromTXT();
        ArrayList<Offer> offers = new ArrayList<>();

        String firstPartOfUrl = "https://www.albion-online-data.com/api/v2/stats/prices/";
        String secondPartOfUrl = "";
        String thirdPartOfUrl = "?locations=";
        String fourthPartOfUrl = "";
        String fifthPartOfUrl = "&qualities=0";

        fourthPartOfUrl = fromCity + "," + toCity;
        //System.out.println(fourthPartOfUrl);

        String url = "";

        int n = 1;

        JSONFromURL jfu = new JSONFromURL();

        for (Item i : items) {
            secondPartOfUrl += i.getId() + ",";
            n++;

            if (n % 19 == 0 || (i.equals(items.get(items.size() - 1)))) {
                secondPartOfUrl = secondPartOfUrl.substring(0, secondPartOfUrl.length() - 1);
                url = firstPartOfUrl + secondPartOfUrl + thirdPartOfUrl + fourthPartOfUrl + fifthPartOfUrl;
                // System.out.println(url);
                JSONArray jsonarray = jfu.callMeOnArray(url);

                for (int j = 0; j < jsonarray.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(j);
                    String itemID = obj.getString("item_id");

                    Item tempItem = items.stream().filter(e -> itemID.equals(e.getId())).findAny().orElse(null);

                    if (tempItem != null && obj.getInt("sell_price_min") > 0) {
                        String city = obj.getString("city");
                        int sellPriceMin = obj.getInt("sell_price_min");
                        if (toCity.contains(city)) sellPriceMin = (int) (sellPriceMin * (100 - auctionTax) / 100);
                        String sellPriceMinDate = obj.getString("sell_price_min_date");
                        int buyPriceMax = obj.getInt("buy_price_max");
                        String buyPriceMaxDate = obj.getString("buy_price_max_date");

                        offers.add(new Offer(tempItem, city, sellPriceMin, sellPriceMinDate, buyPriceMax,
                                buyPriceMaxDate));
                    }
                }

                secondPartOfUrl = "";

            }
        }

        // offers.stream().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));

        return offers;

    }

    public List<Trade> getTrades(String fromCity, String toCity, int profitMinimum, int profitMaximum, int auctionTax)  {

     long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<Trade> trades = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayList<Offer> offers = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            offers = getOffers(fromCity, toCity, auctionTax);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            System.out.println("GetInfoService.java --> getTrades(String fromCity, String toCity, String profitInput, String profitMaximum) --> " + e);
        }

        if (fromCity.contains("FortSterling")) fromCity = fromCity.substring(0, fromCity.indexOf("Sterling")) + " " + fromCity.substring(fromCity.indexOf("Sterling"));
        if (  toCity.contains("FortSterling")) toCity   = toCity  .substring(0,   toCity.indexOf("Sterling")) + " " +   toCity.substring(toCity  .indexOf("Sterling"));


        final String fromCityFinal = fromCity;
        final String toCityFinal = toCity;

        List<Offer> fromOffers = offers.stream()
                .filter(e -> fromCityFinal.contains(e.getCity()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Offer> toOffers = offers.stream()
                .filter(e -> toCityFinal.contains(e.getCity()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        for (int i = 0; i < fromOffers.size(); i++) {
            Offer fromOffer = fromOffers.get(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < toOffers.size(); j++) {
                Offer toOffer = toOffers.get(j);

                if (fromOffer.getItem().getId().equals(toOffer.getItem().getId())) {
                    if ((toOffer.getSellPriceMin() - fromOffer.getSellPriceMin() > profitMinimum) && (toOffer.getSellPriceMin() - fromOffer.getSellPriceMin() <= profitMaximum)) {
                        trades.add(new Trade(fromOffer, toOffer));
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        Collections.sort(trades);

        // trades.stream().forEach(e->System.out.println(e));

         long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

         System.out.println("It took " + (end-start) + " milliseconds!");

        return trades;
    }
```

This is the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.transportfromcitytocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>transportfromcitytocity</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <name>TransportFromCityToCity</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

        <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is the application.properties:

```
server.port=8080
```

Thanks

Comment: Where's the stack trace?

Comment: Please check the console whether there is any error?

Comment: No idea how to check the console. I start it as jar... I have nothing opened.

Comment: And your jar prints output.

Comment: Note also that catching exceptions and then just writing to stdout is not a good habit to get into; it tends to hide errors, and in this case you just continue in an inconsistent state. The stack trace already contains the class, method, and line number where the error occurred, and it's usually better to just let it escape and let Spring handle it. Finally, your `new`s are subject to [this common bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19896870/1189885). Much better to use constructor parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the file is not there. the bytes are in the jar but you can't load it from a path like that. when running it in the IDE the file exists with that path.

`InputStream is ={CLASSNAMEHERE}.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);`

and you can get the bytes and turn to string from there.

```
public class ResourceToString {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String pi  = convertStreamToString(ResourceToString.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("pi.txt"));
    System.out.println(pi);

}
private static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
}
}
```

in this example pi.txt is in my resources folder `\{projDir}\src\main\resources`.

Comment: Exactly how should I change my code? Where should I put this code?

Comment: well i don't know the class name so i can't tell you `Exactly`  see edit in a minute

Comment: not the whole class but use these things in `getItemNamesAndIDsFromTXT`

Comment: Working perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Note that Spring is happy to inject an `@Value("classpath:/pi.txt) InputStream is` for you.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to mavriksc I changed the method to this:

```
public List<Item> getItemNamesAndIDsFromTXT() {

List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

String content =  convertStreamToString(TransportFromCityToCityApplication.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ids"));

List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(content.split("\\n"));


for (String i : lines) {
    String uniqueName = i.substring(i.indexOf(':') + 1, i.lastIndexOf(':')).trim();
    String tier = uniqueName.substring(0, 2);

    String itemName = i.substring(i.lastIndexOf(':') + 2).trim();
    if (uniqueName.contains("@")) {
        itemName = itemName + uniqueName.substring(uniqueName.indexOf('@'));
    }
    items.add(new Item(uniqueName, itemName, tier));

}

return items;
}
```

And it works. So as I see the "classpath" way is not working if you want to use your application outside of the IDE.